# Visa to Oman travelling with a car from UAE

Tags: borders, oman, lithuanian-citizens

I am travelling to Oman with a car from UAE. My car agency (Sixt) promised me they will supply all the needed documents for the car and there should be no issues crossing the border.

[Wikitravel](https://wikitravel.org/en/Oman#Visas) suggests that `Starting March 21st 2018, it will not be possible to receive a visa on arrival, one must apply for a visa online`. However, Ministry of Foreign Affairs from my homeland (I hold Lithuanian citizenship) on their website states that one can get a visa at the border (or at the airport in Oman). [USA Bureau of Consular Affairs](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/International-Travel-Country-Information-Pages/Oman.html) also mentions online visa application, however it also states `Tourist visas (including 2-year multiple entry visitor visas) are also available upon arrival at airports and land crossings.`

- Can one still obtain the visa at the border or should one apply online? Is there any other procedure one should take of?

Comment: There are two completely separate questions, here, and they should be posted separately. I hope you get the answers you need and that your trip goes well!

Comment: By the way, is there any particular reason that you want to go the visa-on-arrival route? You don't mention any disadvantages of applying online, so why not just do that and avoid the uncertainty?

Comment: @DavidRicherby I cannot find any resources on people applying online. It looks like one can still get the visa at the border. I just want to be sure!

Answer (score 2):

Lithuanian citizens are not visa exempt. Another source also suggests you can't get a visa on arrival:

> However, up until now the option has still been there to just get a visa on arrival. As of March 21, 2018, Oman will only issue tourist eVisas. That means the only way to get a tourist visa to Oman will be online, and not at a consulate or on arrival in Oman.

([Non-governmental source](https://onemileatatime.com/oman-new-visa-rules/))

To be safe, I recommend applying for an e-Visa [here](https://www.rop.gov.om/OnlineServices/eVisa/en/).

Comment: The visa application link in your Answer leads to a non-governmental entity. Most countries provide direct on-line links for such applications, and prospective visitors don't have to use (and pay for) a middleman. A brief search revealed a Royal Oman Police link, in English, for Oman visa applications and renewals: https://www.rop.gov.om/OnlineServices/eVisa/en/

Comment: You're welcome. I also reverted the main text "source" link to show it too is non-governmental. I think the "governmental" and "non-governmental" info is useful for readers to see without having to follow the link.